# How To jQuery Set Focus To A Section-div-div-div tab?

Tags: jquery, html, select, tabs, focus

I have a section that looks like the following. When I switch parameters above this that reload the data, I want the first div to be the active one, but instead it stays with the one I was last on and loads it with the chart that belongs in the first tab.   How do I set the first tab as the active tab?  I've tried select, focus, any number of things to no avail.

UPDATE: Based on the first response I received, I think I need to clarify this more.  The first load of this works great. Then the user can make selections in another part of the screen (changing job type and location) I hide the chart area, and when they click a button to refresh the charts that are loaded into my example area here, I need the first tab (#rates) to be the active one when I unhide the chart area. Right now, it loads the chart meant for the first tab into the second or third tab, whichever was last active before they changed the parameters.  So, I'm looking for some command or short function, something along the lines of $('#rates').select() or focus(), or even $('a[href="#rates"]').focus(), but none of those work.

```
<section id="trendData" class="panel panel-default" style="display: none; width: 60%; min-width:600px; margin-left: 30px;">
    <header class="panel-heading bg-light">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            <li class="active"><a href="#rates" data-toggle="tab">Rates</a></li>
            <li><a href="#duration" data-toggle="tab">Open Duration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#jobs" data-toggle="tab">Number of Jobs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active activeRates" id="rates"    name="rates"    style="height:500px; width:90%; text-align:center;"></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="duration" name="duration" style="height:500px; width:90%; text-align:center;"></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="jobs"     name="jobs"     style="height:500px; width:90%; text-align:center;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the parent mode.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("span").parent().css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
});
```

```css
.ancestors * { 
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="ancestors">body (great-great-grandparent)
  <div style="width:500px;">div (great-grandparent)
    <ul>ul (grandparent)  
      <li>li (direct parent)
        <span>span</span>
      </li>
    </ul>   
  </div>
</body>
```

The parent() method returns the direct parent element of the selected element.

The DOM tree: This method only traverse a single level up the DOM tree. To traverse all the way up to the document's root element (to return grandparents or other ancestors), use the parents() or the parentsUntil() method.

Tip: To traverse a single level down the DOM tree, or all the way down to the last descendant (to return children or other descendants), use the children() or find() method.

Comment: Selcuk, thank you, but I feel like you're answering someone else's queston. I have no idea how to apply that to my situation.

I was hoping / looking for something along the lines of:
    $('this identifier').focus();
or something in that genre.  I truly don't know how to use what you just wrote. Sorry.

Comment: Since I am unable to answer my own post due to some answer ban, the answer is here:

Answer: Location, location, location.

I was putting the right code in the wrong spot. When I relocated the command:

    $('a[href="#rates"]').click();

to one of the first actions upon button click, it all worked perfectly. The first tab now gets selected and loaded correctly.